# Get an int value from a JTable cell

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that puts user input values into a JTable, one column holds siteNumber. I need to be able to check if that siteNumber is already used. Heres my code for getValueAt().

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    switch(col) {
    case 0:
        return (listSites.get(row).getNameReserving());

    case 1:
        return (DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).
                format(listSites.get(row).getCheckIn().getTime()));

    case 2:
        return (listSites.get(row).getDaysStaying());

    case 3:
        return (listSites.get(row).getSiteNumber());

    case 4:
        if(listSites.get(row) instanceof Tent)
            return("Tents: " + ((Tent) listSites.get(row))
                    .getNumOfTenters());
        else
            return ("Power bought: " + ((RV) listSites.get(row))
                    .getPower() + " Amps");

    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ideally it would be a simple check of if(getValueAt(row, col) == siteNumber), but this is comparing an Object and an Integer, and I can't figure out a way around this? this is for a University project so a lot of it isn't my original ideas and i'm really just trying to figure out how they want me to do it.

listSites is an ArrayList of Sites which is my super class.

Sorry if I'm being stupid but i'm really struggling with figuring this out.

Comment: You can use like this. `if (Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row, col) == siteNumber)`. Try this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact problem, but if you're getting an item from row 3, then what is returned is as specified by this call: `return (listSites.get(row).getSiteNumber());`. And you can cast the Object returned to the type specified by your Site class's `getSiteNumber()` method. I am assuming that it's returning ... an Integer (you don't tell us)? If so, cast it to that and use it.

---

What it sounds like you need has little to do with the JTable or the `getValueAt(...)` method. Instead it sounds like you need input verification for where the user is trying to enter data, here likely in your user entry dialog code. In that code, you'd search through the listSites collection making sure that a duplicate site number is not being entered, and if it is, warn the user about their error, and prevent data entry. Perhaps you want to use an [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) attached to a JTextField.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info, you were right in assuming it's an int. I did what you said, and used a for loop to search multiple rows, and casted that line. It's not giving any errors, but the code still isn't working for me

Comment: @Itheyln: I would love to help you further, but I'm not sure how, as you need to give us a lot more details on just how things are not working. `"still isn't working for me"` doesn't give us much to go on. Please remember that we're at a distinct disadvantage since we only can see code that you show us and can only understand issues that you fully explain to us. Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, so my program has a GUI interface that uses a dialog for input, the input is meant to be then put into my JTable. Right now i'm trying to make it so that when you try and submit user input, it will check the table to make sure there are no duplicate siteNumbers. Currently my code will allow multiple entries into the JTable despite them having the same siteNumber. I have code that calls a method that checks if there is a duplicate once they try and submit the user input. the method called has an integer parameter that is used to compare with the siteNumbers of the JTable.

Comment: Currently I believe that my method that checks to see if the JTable has duplicate values is not checking the JTable correctly. There is little point is posting this method as it's essentially empty. Any general concepts on how i can retrieve a value from the JTable and be able to compare it with and integer value would be incredibly helpful. as I stated earlier when i tried to cast the listSites.get(row).getSiteNumber into an Int, my method still could not catch when there were duplicate values.

Comment: @Itheyln: consider editing your question and putting all pertinent information there. That way others who are smarter than me can also help you out. Also show pertinent code, best if you could create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand your problem and then help you.